# How to identify if ion-input value has been cleared?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have an ion-input that populate a variable. when the user click on clear button I need to clear that variable.
I don’t know how to understand when the user clear the button. how is it possible to do that?

I use Ionic + Stenciljs without a framework

This is my button code (is not a part of a form)

```
 <ion-input
                clear-input
                name="password"
                type="password"
                placeholder={i18n("Password")}
                class="selected_password"
                required
                onInput={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}>
            </ion-input>
```

The only way that I have found as a workaround is to listen to ionchange and check if the value it's empty or not.
It's really annoying that there isn't an event as ionClear or something else to deal with this.

Comment: could you add your code ? Is your input part of a form ?

Comment: edited the question. no part of a form

Comment: unfortunatly, I think your workaround "listen to ionchange and check if the value it's empty or not" is the best way for now. For what I've check there is no method for that. Or maybe try to find the cross button in the HTML, focus it and add a click event, or create yourself the x button and the clear method (without using the clearInput option) so you'll have total control on it

Answer (score 0):

ion-input tag already has to clear the input, you just wrote it wrong:
try:

```
   <ion-input
            clearInput
            name="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder={i18n("Password")}
            class="selected_password"
            required
            onInput={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}>
        </ion-input>
```

just change 'clear-input' to 'clearInput' and the button 'x' will appear at the end of the ion-input.

Comment: The X icon already appears. the problem is that I'm not able to detect WHEN the user click on the X icon

Comment: Oh I see, and you don't want to check (onChange) method and see if it's empty or not... Well i think there is no way to do this sorry, ionic doesn't provide an event for that. Good luck!